# A telephone book command line program in ANSI C

Tags: c, linked-list, console, database, edit-distance

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143224/a-telephone-book-command-line-program-in-ansi-c-follow-up).)

**Introduction**

I was in the mood for some C code and wrote this program for handling a personal telephone record book. One of the goals is strict portability; the code compiles with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall ...` silently. The second goal is being prepared for dealing with problems (out of memory, file I/O errors).

**Usage**

The program creates and works on a file called `.telephone_book` that is placed in the user's home directory.

In order to add new record:

```
./tbook --add Claus Santa 040-1234567
```

In order to list all records:

```
./tbook # list all
./tbook blah # list all records whose last name is closest to "blah" by Levenshtein distance
./tbook - blah # list all records whose first name is closest to "blah" by Levenshtein distance
./tbook bluh blah # list all records whose both last and first names are closest to "bluh blah" by Levenshtein distance
```

The output may be something like:

> ```
> ----------+------------+------------------+---
> Last name | First name | Telephone number | ID
> ----------+------------+------------------+---
> Bro       | Vector     | 11               | 1 
> Efremov   | Rodion     | 8055             | 2 
> Funk      | Funky      | 12321            | 3 
> ----------+------------+------------------+---
> Gates     | Bill       | 677              | 4 
> Minogue   | Kylie      | 4401             | 5 
> Ryazanov  | Viktor     | 3454             | 6
> ```

In order to delete records by their IDs:

```
./tbook --remove ID1 ID2 ... IDn
```

Here are all 5 source files:

**telephone_book.h**:

```c
#ifndef TELEPHONE_BOOK_H
#define TELEPHONE_BOOK_H

#include <stdio.h>

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure holds a single telephone book record.                         *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
    char* telephone_number;
    int id;
} telephone_book_record;

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure defines a linked list node for the telephone book record      *
* list.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct telephone_book_record_list_node {
    telephone_book_record* record;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* next;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* prev;
} telephone_book_record_list_node;

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure holds a doubly-linked list of telephone book records.         *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* head;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* tail;
    int size;
} telephone_book_record_list;




/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the length of the telephone book record list.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_size(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes a new telephone book record.                       *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new telephone book record or NULL if something goes wrong.         *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record* telephone_book_record_alloc(const char* last_name,
                                                   const char* first_name,
                                                   const char* phone_number,
                                                   int id);

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees the memory occupied by the telephone book record: all existing fields  *
* and the actual record.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_free(telephone_book_record* record);




/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes an empty telephone book record list.               *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new empty telephone book record list or NULL if something goes     *
* wrong.                                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

/*******************************************************************************
* Appends the argument telephone book record to the tail of the argument       *
* telephone book record list.                                                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a zero value if the operation was successfull. A non-zero value is   *
* returned if something fails.                                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_add_record(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                          telephone_book_record* record);

/*******************************************************************************
* Removes and returns the telephone book record that has 'id' as its record ID.*
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns NULL if something fails or the list does not contain record with ID  *
* 'id'. Otherwise, a removed record is returned.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record*
telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                        int id);

/*******************************************************************************
* Reconstructs the telephone book record list from a file pointed to by the    *
* argument file handle.                                                        *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns the record list on success, and NULL on failure.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(FILE* f);

/*******************************************************************************
* Writes the entire contents of the telephone record list to a specified file  *
* handle.                                                                      *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                             FILE* f);

/*******************************************************************************
* Sorts the telephone records. The last name of each record is the primary     *
* sorting key, and the first name of each record is the secondary sorting key. *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if the sorting could not be    *
* completed.                                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_sort(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that each telephone book record has a unique ID.                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory occupied by the argument telephone book record list.    *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_list_free(telephone_book_record_list* list);

#endif /* TELEPHONE_BOOK_H */
```

**telephone_book.c**:

```c
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "64"
#define MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH 65

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the length of the telephone book record list.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_size(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    return list ? list->size : -1;
}

static telephone_book_record_list_node*
telephone_book_record_list_node_alloc(telephone_book_record* record)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* node;

    if (!record)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if (!node)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    node->record = record;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->prev = NULL;

    return node;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes a new telephone book record.                       *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new telephone book record or NULL if something goes wrong.         *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record* telephone_book_record_alloc(const char* last_name,
                                                   const char* first_name,
                                                   const char* phone_number,
                                                   int id)
{
    telephone_book_record* record = malloc(sizeof *record);

    if (!record)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record->last_name        = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(last_name) + 1));
    record->first_name       = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(first_name) + 1));
    record->telephone_number = malloc(sizeof(char) *
                                      (strlen(phone_number) + 1));
    record->id = id;

    strcpy(record->last_name, last_name);
    strcpy(record->first_name, first_name);
    strcpy(record->telephone_number, phone_number);

    return record;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees the memory occupied by the telephone book record: all existing fields  *
* and the actual record.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_free(telephone_book_record* record)
{
    if (!record)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (record->first_name)
    {
        free(record->first_name);
    }

    if (record->last_name)
    {
        free(record->last_name);
    }

    if (record->telephone_number)
    {
        free(record->telephone_number);
    }

    free(record);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes an empty telephone book record list.               *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new empty telephone book record list or NULL if something goes     *
* wrong.                                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_alloc()
{
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list = malloc(sizeof *record_list);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record_list->head = NULL;
    record_list->tail = NULL;
    record_list->size = 0;
    return record_list;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Appends the argument telephone book record to the tail of the argument       *
* telephone book record list.                                                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a zero value if the operation was successfull. A non-zero value is   *
* returned if something fails.                                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_add_record(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                          telephone_book_record* record)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* new_node;

    if (!list || !record)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    new_node = telephone_book_record_list_node_alloc(record);

    if (!new_node)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (list->head)
    {
        new_node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = new_node;
    }

    list->tail = new_node;
    list->size++;
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Removes a telephone book record that has 'id' as its record ID.              *
* ---                                                                          *
* On error or ID mismatch returns NULL. Otherwise the record with the same ID  *
* (which is removed) is returned.                                              *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record*
telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                        int id)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* next_node;
    telephone_book_record* removed_record;

    if (!list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;

        /* Since the program makes sure that all IDs are unique, we can */
        /* return as soon as we remove the first match. */
        if (current_node->record->id == id)
        {
            if (current_node->prev)
            {
                current_node->prev->next = current_node->next;
            }
            else
            {
                list->head = current_node->next;
            }

            if (current_node->next)
            {
                current_node->next->prev = current_node->prev;
            }
            else
            {
                list->tail = current_node->prev;
            }

            removed_record = current_node->record;
            free(current_node);
            return removed_record;
        }

        current_node = next_node;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Reconstructs the telephone book record list from a file pointed to by the    *
* argument file handle.                                                        *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns the record list on success, and NULL on failure.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(FILE* f)
{
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    char last_name_token   [MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    char first_name_token  [MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    char phone_number_token[MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    int  id_holder;
    int read_result;

    if (!f)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    if (!record_list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f))
    {
        read_result = fscanf(f,
                             "%" MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %"  MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %"  MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %d\n",
                             last_name_token,
                             first_name_token,
                             phone_number_token,
                             &id_holder);

        if (read_result == 4)
        {
            current_record = telephone_book_record_alloc(last_name_token,
                                                         first_name_token,
                                                         phone_number_token,
                                                         id_holder);
            if (!current_record)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for a telephone book "
                      "record.", stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
                return NULL;
            }

            telephone_book_record_list_add_record(record_list, current_record);
        }
    }

    return record_list;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Writes the entire contents of the telephone record list to a specified file  *
* handle.                                                                      *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                             FILE* f)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    if (!list || !f)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        fprintf(f,
                "%s %s %s %d\n",
                current_node->record->last_name,
                current_node->record->first_name,
                current_node->record->telephone_number,
                current_node->record->id);

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Defines a telephone book record comparator. The last name of a record is the *
* primary sorting key, and the first name is the secondary sorting key.        *
* ---
* Returns zero, if both the input records have the same last and first name.   *
* If the first entry should precede the second, a negative value is returned.  *
* If the second entry should precede the first, a positive value is returned.  *
*******************************************************************************/
static int record_cmp(const void* pa, const void* pb)
{
    int c;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* a =
    *(telephone_book_record_list_node *const *) pa;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* b =
    *(telephone_book_record_list_node *const *) pb;

    c = strcmp(a->record->last_name, b->record->last_name);

    if (c)
    {
        return c;
    }

    return strcmp(a->record->first_name, b->record->first_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Sorts the telephone records. The last name of each record is the primary     *
* sorting key, and the first name of each record is the secondary sorting key. *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if the sorting could not be    *
* completed.                                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_sort(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node** array;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    int list_length;
    int index;

    if (!list)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    list_length = telephone_book_record_list_size(list);

    if (list_length == 0)
    {
        /* Nothing to sort. */
        return 0;
    }

    array = malloc(list_length * sizeof *array);

    if (!array)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    for (index = 0;
         index < list_length;
         index++, current_node = current_node->next)
    {
        array[index] = current_node;
    }

    qsort(array, list_length, sizeof *array, record_cmp);

    /* Relink the nodes: */
    list->head = array[0];
    list->tail = array[list_length - 1];

    list->head->prev = NULL;
    list->tail->next = NULL;

    for (index = 0; index < list_length - 1; ++index)
    {
        array[index]->next = array[index + 1];
    }

    for (index = 1; index < list_length; ++index)
    {
        array[index]->prev = array[index - 1];
    }

    /* Freeing memory! */
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that each telephone book record has an unique ID.                 *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    int id;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    if (!list)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    id = 0;
    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_node->record->id = ++id;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory occupied by the argument telephone book record list.    *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_list_free(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* next_node;

    if (!list)
    {
        return;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        telephone_book_record_free(current_node->record);
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }

    free(list);
}
```

**telephone_book_utils.h**:

```c
#ifndef TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H
#define TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include "telephone_book.h"

/*******************************************************************************
* This structures holds the string required for neat result output.            *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    char* title_string;
    char* separator_string;
    char* record_format_string;
} output_table_strings;

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the character representing a path separator character ('/' or '\')   *
* used on the current platform.                                                *
*******************************************************************************/
char separator();

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a C string representing the full path to the telephone book record   *
* file.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns all format strings for printing the record list.         *
*******************************************************************************/
output_table_strings*
output_table_strings_create(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns a structure containing all format strings necessary for  *
* printing the telephone book record list.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
void output_table_strings_free(output_table_strings* output_table_strs);

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the format string for nifty printing the removed records.            *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_removed_record_output_format_string(telephone_book_record_list* list);

#endif /* TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H */
```

**telephone_book_utils.c**:

```c
#include "telephone_book_utils.h"
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

const char* TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME = ".telephone_book";

static const char* TITLE_LAST_NAME          = "Last name";
static const char* TITLE_FIRST_NAME         = "First name";
static const char* TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER   = "Telephone number";
static const char* TITLE_CONTACT_ID         = "ID";

static const size_t ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY = 40;
static const size_t FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY    = 100;

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the character representing a path separator character ('/' or '\')   *
* used on the current platform.                                                *
*******************************************************************************/
char separator()
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    return '\\';
#else
    return '/';
#endif
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a C string representing the full path to the telephone book record   *
* file.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_telephone_record_book_file_path()
{
    char* home_directory;
    char* telephone_record_book_file_path;
    size_t home_directory_name_length;

    home_directory = getenv("HOME");

    if (!home_directory)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    home_directory_name_length = strlen(home_directory);

    /* Allocate the space for the entire */
    telephone_record_book_file_path =
    malloc(sizeof(char)
            * (home_directory_name_length
               + 2 + strlen(TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME)));

    if (!telephone_record_book_file_path)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(telephone_record_book_file_path, home_directory);
    telephone_record_book_file_path[home_directory_name_length] = separator();
    strcpy(&telephone_record_book_file_path[home_directory_name_length + 1],
           TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME);

    return telephone_record_book_file_path;
}



/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and sets a row separator string.                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
char* load_separator_string(size_t max_last_name_token_length,
                            size_t max_first_name_token_length,
                            size_t max_telephone_number_token_length,
                            size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length)
{
    size_t index;
    size_t i;
    char* separator_string =
    malloc(sizeof(char) *
           (max_last_name_token_length + 1) +
           (max_first_name_token_length + 2) +
           (max_telephone_number_token_length + 2) +
           (max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1) + 4);

    if (!separator_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the row separator string.",
              stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (i = 0; i != max_last_name_token_length + 1; ++i)
    {
        separator_string[i] = '-';
    }

    separator_string[max_last_name_token_length + 1] = '+';

    index = max_last_name_token_length + 2;

    for (i = 0; i != max_first_name_token_length + 2; ++i)
    {
        separator_string[index++] = '-';
    }

    separator_string[index++] = '+';

    for (i = 0; i != max_telephone_number_token_length + 2; ++i)
    {
        separator_string[index++] = '-';
    }

    separator_string[index++] = '+';

    for (i = 0; i != max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1; ++i)
    {
        separator_string[index++] = '-';
    }

    separator_string[index++] = '\0';
    return separator_string;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns a structure containing all format strings necessary for  *
* printing the telephone book record list.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
output_table_strings*
output_table_strings_create(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    size_t max_last_name_token_length        = strlen(TITLE_LAST_NAME);
    size_t max_first_name_token_length       = strlen(TITLE_FIRST_NAME);
    size_t max_telephone_number_token_length = strlen(TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER);
    size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length   = strlen(TITLE_CONTACT_ID);

    size_t last_name_token_length;
    size_t first_name_token_length;
    size_t telephone_number_token_length;
    size_t telephone_contact_id_length;

    output_table_strings* output_table;

    char* record_format_string;
    char* title_string;
    char* separator_string;
    char* id_holder_string;
    char* title_string_format;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    if (!list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table */
    output_table = malloc(sizeof *output_table);

    if (!output_table)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the output format structures.",
              stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, id_holder_string */
    id_holder_string = malloc(ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!id_holder_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the ID field holder.", stderr);
        free(output_table);
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_record = current_node->record;

        last_name_token_length  = strlen(current_record->last_name);
        first_name_token_length = strlen(current_record->first_name);
        telephone_number_token_length =
        strlen(current_record->telephone_number);

        sprintf(id_holder_string, "%d", current_record->id);
        telephone_contact_id_length = strlen(id_holder_string);

        max_last_name_token_length = MAX(max_last_name_token_length,
                                         last_name_token_length);

        max_first_name_token_length = MAX(max_first_name_token_length,
                                          first_name_token_length);

        max_telephone_number_token_length =
            MAX(max_telephone_number_token_length,
                telephone_number_token_length);

        max_telephone_contact_id_length = MAX(max_telephone_contact_id_length,
                                              telephone_contact_id_length);

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table */
    free(id_holder_string);

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, record_format_string */
    record_format_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!record_format_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the format string.", stderr);
        free(output_table);
        return NULL;
    }

    sprintf(record_format_string,
            "%%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zuzu\n",
            max_last_name_token_length,
            max_first_name_token_length,
            max_telephone_number_token_length,
            max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    /* @ALLOC: output_table, record_format_string, title_string */
    title_string =
        malloc(sizeof(char) *
               (max_last_name_token_length + 1) +
               (max_first_name_token_length + 2) +
               (max_telephone_number_token_length + 2) +
               (max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1) + 4);

    if (!title_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the title string.", stderr);
        free(output_table);
        free(record_format_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, record_format_string,
                  title_string, title_string_format */
    title_string_format = malloc(sizeof(char) * FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!title_string_format)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the title string format.",
              stderr);
        free(output_table);
        free(record_format_string);
        free(title_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    sprintf(title_string_format,
            "%%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zus",
            max_last_name_token_length,
            max_first_name_token_length,
            max_telephone_number_token_length,
            max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    sprintf(title_string,
            title_string_format,
            TITLE_LAST_NAME,
            TITLE_FIRST_NAME,
            TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
            TITLE_CONTACT_ID);

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, record_format_string, title_string */
    free(title_string_format);

    separator_string =
        load_separator_string(max_last_name_token_length,
                              max_first_name_token_length,
                              max_telephone_number_token_length,
                              max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    if (!separator_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the separator string.",
              stderr);
        free(output_table);
        free(record_format_string);
        free(title_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    output_table->title_string = title_string;
    output_table->separator_string = separator_string;
    output_table->record_format_string = record_format_string;

    return output_table;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory alloated by the output table format strings.            *
*******************************************************************************/
void output_table_strings_free(output_table_strings* output_table_strs)
{
    if (!output_table_strs)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (output_table_strs->record_format_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->record_format_string);
    }

    if (output_table_strs->separator_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->separator_string);
    }

    if (output_table_strs->title_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->title_string);
    }

    free(output_table_strs);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the format string for nifty printing the removed records.            *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_removed_record_output_format_string(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    size_t max_last_name_token_length        = 0;
    size_t max_first_name_token_length       = 0;
    size_t max_telephone_number_token_length = 0;
    size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length   = 0;

    size_t last_name_token_length;
    size_t first_name_token_length;
    size_t telephone_number_token_length;
    size_t telephone_contact_id_length;

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string */
    char* format_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY);
    char* id_holder_string;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    if (!format_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the format string.", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string, id_holder_string */
    id_holder_string = malloc(ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!id_holder_string)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the ID field holder.", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_record = current_node->record;

        last_name_token_length  = strlen(current_record->last_name);
        first_name_token_length = strlen(current_record->first_name);
        telephone_number_token_length =
                                  strlen(current_record->telephone_number);

        sprintf(id_holder_string, "%d", current_record->id);
        telephone_contact_id_length = strlen(id_holder_string);

        max_last_name_token_length = MAX(max_last_name_token_length,
                                         last_name_token_length);

        max_first_name_token_length = MAX(max_first_name_token_length,
                                          first_name_token_length);

        max_telephone_number_token_length =
        MAX(max_telephone_number_token_length,
            telephone_number_token_length);

        max_telephone_contact_id_length = MAX(max_telephone_contact_id_length,
                                              telephone_contact_id_length);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    sprintf(format_string,
            "%%-%zus %%-%zus %%-%zus %%-%zuzu\n",
            max_last_name_token_length,
            max_first_name_token_length,
            max_telephone_number_token_length,
            max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string */
    free(id_holder_string);
    return format_string;
}
```

**main.c**:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include "telephone_book_utils.h"

static const char* OPTION_ADD_SHORT = "-a";
static const char* OPTION_ADD_LONG  = "--add";

static const char* OPTION_REMOVE_SHORT = "-r";
static const char* OPTION_REMOVE_LONG  = "--remove";

static const char* OPTION_HELP_SHORT = "-h";
static const char* OPTION_HELP_LONG  = "--help";

static const size_t RECORDS_PER_BLOCK = 3;

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the smallest of 'a', 'b', and 'c'.                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t min3(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c)
{
    if (a < b)
    {
        if (c < a)
        {
            return c;
        }

        return a;
    }

    /* b <= a */
    if (c < b)
    {
        return c;
    }

    return b;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the help message to the standard output.                              *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_help(char* executable_name)
{
    char path_separator = separator();
    int executable_name_length = (int) strlen(executable_name);
    int i;

    /* Doing my own basename for the sake of portability. */
    for (i = executable_name_length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (executable_name[i] == path_separator)
        {
            executable_name = &executable_name[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Usage: %s -a    LAST FIRST NUMBER\n", executable_name);
    printf("       %s --add LAST FIRST NUMBER\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    printf("       %s -r       ID1 ID2 ... IDn\n", executable_name);
    printf("       %s --remove ID1 ID2 ... IDn\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    printf("(1)    %s\n",                      executable_name);
    printf("(2)    %s LAST_EXPR\n",            executable_name);
    printf("(3)    %s - FIRST_EXPR\n",         executable_name);
    printf("(4)    %s LAST_EXPR FIRST_EXPR\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    puts("Where: -a or --add for adding one new book entry.");
    puts("       -r or --remove for removing book entries by their IDs.");
    puts("");
    puts("(1) List all book entries in order.");
    puts("(2) Match by last name and list the closest book entries.");
    puts("(3) Match by first name and list the closest book entries.");
    puts("(4) Match by both last and first names and list the closest book "
         "entries");
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the Levenshtein distance algorithm.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t edit_distance(char* word1,
                            char* word2,
                            size_t length1,
                            size_t length2)
{
    int cost;

    if (length1 == 0)
    {
        return length2;
    }

    if (length2 == 0)
    {
        return length1;
    }

    cost = tolower(word1[length1 - 1]) ==
           tolower(word2[length2 - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

    return min3(edit_distance(word1, word2, length1, length2 - 1) + 1,
                edit_distance(word1, word2, length1 - 1, length2) + 1,
                edit_distance(word1, word2, length1 - 1, length2 - 1) + cost);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Computes the Levenshtein disance between words 'word1' and 'word2'.          *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t compute_edit_distance(char* word1, char* word2)
{
    return edit_distance(word1, word2, strlen(word1), strlen(word2));
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements listing the telephone book records.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
int command_list_telephone_book_records_impl(
                        telephone_book_record_list* record_list,
                        char* last_name,
                        char* first_name)
{
    size_t best_tentative_distance = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    size_t temp_distance;
    size_t i;
    output_table_strings* output_strings;
    telephone_book_record* record;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list* best_record_list =
        telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    /* ALLOCATED: best_record_list */
    if (!best_record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate the best record list.", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    current_node = record_list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        temp_distance =
        (last_name ?
            compute_edit_distance(last_name,
                                  current_node->record->last_name) : 0) +
        (first_name ?
            compute_edit_distance(first_name,
                                  current_node->record->first_name) : 0);

        if (best_tentative_distance > temp_distance)
        {
            /* 'temp_distance' improves the best known edit distance,     */
            /* clear the current best list and append the current record: */
            telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
            best_record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

            if (!best_record_list)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate new best record list.", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            record = telephone_book_record_alloc(
                            current_node->record->last_name,
                            current_node->record->first_name,
                            current_node->record->telephone_number,
                            current_node->record->id);

            if (!record)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate a copy record.", stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(best_record_list, record))
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot add a new record to the best list.",
                      stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                telephone_book_record_free(record);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            best_tentative_distance = temp_distance;
        }
        else if (best_tentative_distance == temp_distance)
        {
            /* Append the current record to the best list: */
            record = telephone_book_record_alloc(
                            current_node->record->last_name,
                            current_node->record->first_name,
                            current_node->record->telephone_number,
                            current_node->record->id);

            if (!record)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate a copy record.", stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }


            if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(best_record_list, record))
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot add a new record to the best list.",
                      stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                telephone_book_record_free(record);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    output_strings = output_table_strings_create(best_record_list);

    if (!output_strings)
    {
        telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(output_strings->separator_string);
    puts(output_strings->title_string);
    puts(output_strings->separator_string);

    current_node = best_record_list->head;
    i = 0;

    while (current_node)
    {
        printf(output_strings->record_format_string,
               current_node->record->last_name,
               current_node->record->first_name,
               current_node->record->telephone_number,
               current_node->record->id);

        current_node = current_node->next;
        ++i;

        if (current_node && i % RECORDS_PER_BLOCK == 0)
        {
            puts(output_strings->separator_string);
        }
    }

    output_table_strings_free(output_strings);
    telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the command for listing the records.                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_list_telephone_book_records(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    char* last_name;
    char* first_name;

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(get_telephone_record_book_file_path(), "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* If fails, silently ignore: */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    /* Does not ask for resources, should be OK: */
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    /* "w" means overwrite the file. */
    f = fopen(file_name, "w");

    if (f)
    {
        /* Write the file back. It will update the order of the records and */
        /* fix the record IDs, if needed. */
        telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    last_name  = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : NULL;
    first_name = argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : NULL;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0)
    {
        /* Match all last names: */
        last_name = NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: record_list */
    free(file_name);

    return command_list_telephone_book_records_impl(record_list,
                                                    last_name,
                                                    first_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the command for adding a new record.                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_add_record(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record* record;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list, record */
    record = telephone_book_record_alloc(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], -1);

    if (!record)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the new record.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(record_list, record))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot add the new entry to the record book.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_free(record);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Even if the following two functions fail, proceed further. */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    f = fopen(file_name, "w");
    free(file_name);

    if (!f)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot open the record book file.", stderr);
        /* 'record' is contained in 'record_list' so is freed by it: */
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot update the record book file.", stderr);
    }

    fclose(f);
    /* 'record' is contained in 'record_list' so is freed by it: */
    telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the commmand for removing records by their IDs.                      *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_remove_records(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record_list* removed_record_list;
    telephone_book_record* removed_record;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    char* removed_record_format;
    int arg_index;
    int id;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        puts("Warning: no record IDs given. Nothing to remove.");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list, removed_record_list */
    removed_record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    if (!removed_record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the list of removed records.",
              stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Even if the following two functions fail, proceed further. */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    f = fopen(file_name, "w");

    /* ALLOCATED: record_list, removed_record_list */
    free(file_name); /* We do not need 'file_name' anymore. */

    if (!f)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot open the record book file for writing.", stderr);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg_index = 2; arg_index < argc; ++arg_index)
    {
        sscanf(argv[arg_index], "%d", &id);
        removed_record = telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(record_list,
                                                                 id);

        if (removed_record)
        {
            telephone_book_record_list_add_record(removed_record_list,
                                                  removed_record);
        }
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot update the record book file.", stderr);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
        fclose(f);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(f);

    printf("Number of records to remove: %d, removed: %d.\n",
           argc - 2,
           telephone_book_record_list_size(removed_record_list));
    puts("List of removed entries:");
    current_node = removed_record_list->head;
    removed_record_format =
        get_removed_record_output_format_string(removed_record_list);

    while (current_node)
    {
        if (removed_record_format)
        {
            printf(removed_record_format,
                   current_node->record->last_name,
                   current_node->record->first_name,
                   current_node->record->telephone_number,
                   current_node->record->id);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Fallback format output: */
            printf("%s, %s - %s, ID %d\n",
                   current_node->record->last_name,
                   current_node->record->first_name,
                   current_node->record->telephone_number,
                   current_node->record->id);
        }

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    if (removed_record_format)
    {
        free(removed_record_format);
    }

    telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        return command_list_telephone_book_records(argc, argv);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_HELP_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_HELP_LONG) == 0)
    {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_ADD_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_ADD_LONG) == 0)
    {
        return command_add_record(argc, argv);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_REMOVE_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_REMOVE_LONG) == 0)
    {
        return command_remove_records(argc, argv);
    }

    return command_list_telephone_book_records(argc, argv);
}
```

**Critique request**

As always, I want to hear everything you have to say, for example:

- idiomatic C
- naming
- API
- modularity
- robustness
- efficiency

Comment: strongly suggest turning up the compiler warnings because the posted code has two calls to function: `telephone_book_record_list_free()` that do not have preceding prototype for the function.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu99` )

Comment: @user3629249 Disagreed on `-std=gnu99`: I want to keep it ANSI.

Comment: If you use `-ansi`, then expect that certain functions (all the `posix` functions for example) will not be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have built in a cultural assumption that everybody has a first name and a last name, which is not true, and that first and last have the same role everywhere.  The changes to fix that are probably quite extensive, unfortunately.

---

You're not consistent with your include ordering.  I normally recommend that you include your own headers first, and Standard Library headers last - this helps identify where your own headers may have made unjustified assumptions that standard headers were included first.

On a related note, you might want to move `telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file()` and `telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file()` into a different header (perhaps called `telephone_io.h`), to avoid `telephone.h` dragging in `<stdio.h>` to every translation unit that includes it.  Unfortunately, [you can't just provide a compatible definition for `FILE`](//stackoverflow.com/q/3882346), or that would be preferable.

---

```
char separator();
```

Is there a reason you made this a function, rather than a simple constant?

---

In loops like this:

```
for (i = 0; i != max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1; ++i)
```

I normally prefer to use `<` or `<=` as the conditional.  It's more idiomatic, and avoids some errors caused by modifying `i` within the loop body.  And in modern C, you can declare `i` within the `for`, which makes it clearer that you won't be using the value afterwards.

Looking at the Pascal-style repetitive loops there, I'd be inclined to refactor with a small function:

```
/**
 * Write /n/ copies of character /c/ into string buffer /s/.
 * Note that no null is written.
 * Returns the next write position.
 */
char *write_separator(char *s, char c, int n) {
    while (n-->0)
        *s++ = c;
    return s;
}
```

or even (with `#include <string.h>`):

```
char *write_separator(char *s, char c, int n) {
    memset(s, c, n);
    return s+n;
}
```

---

I generally avoid this sort of thing at the low levels:

```
if (!separator_string)
{
    fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the row separator string.",
          stderr);
    return NULL;
}
```

Prefer to return an error indication, and leave it up to the calling code to decide how to report it.  In a GUI version, you probably want to display a GUI message rather than reporting to `stderr`.

Also, note that you don't free the successfully allocated memory in any of these error paths, giving a memory leak that's hard to track down.

---

This looks contorted:

```
sprintf(record_format_string,
        "%%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zuzu\n",
```

It's probably clearer to use `%*s` in the format string, and pass the length with each call.

---

This one's really weird:

```
   title_string =
        malloc(sizeof(char) *
               (max_last_name_token_length + 1) +
               (max_first_name_token_length + 2) +
               (max_telephone_number_token_length + 2) +
               (max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1) + 4);
```

`sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition; multiplying by it makes you look ignorant.  Also, it's not clear why only the last-name token should be multiplied by 1 - the line breaks and parentheses serve to deceive the reader here!  It may be simpler and more consistent to ask `snprintf` to compute that sum for you using the same format string you'll be printing with (at a small performance cost).

Comment: All good points. What comes to the cultural aspect, can you mention one culture/region where the first name/last name separation does not apply?

Comment: @coderodde - I do know one person (residing in Great Britain) who has a single name rather than first (middle) last.  And many names in East Asia are written with family name first - that's quite common in China and Korea.  I'm not an internationalization expert, though, so willing to sit corrected!

Comment: [relevant article](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Where I am, people have two surnames, one from the father and one from the mother, and one or usually more forenames.