# A telephone book command line program in ANSI C - follow-up

Tags: c, linked-list, console, database, edit-distance

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144279/a-telephone-book-command-line-program-in-ansi-c-follow-up-2).)

This question is a slight improvement over [A telephone book command line program in ANSI C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142716/a-telephone-book-command-line-program-in-ansi-c)

I have incorporated almost all points stated by [Toby Speight](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight).

Now I have this:

> telephone_book.h

```
#ifndef TELEPHONE_BOOK_H
#define TELEPHONE_BOOK_H

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure holds a single telephone book record.                         *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
    char* telephone_number;
    int id;
} telephone_book_record;

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure defines a linked list node for the telephone book record      *
* list.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct telephone_book_record_list_node {
    telephone_book_record* record;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* next;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* prev;
} telephone_book_record_list_node;

/*******************************************************************************
* This structure holds a doubly-linked list of telephone book records.         *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* head;
    struct telephone_book_record_list_node* tail;
    int size;
} telephone_book_record_list;




/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the length of the telephone book record list.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_size(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes a new telephone book record.                       *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new telephone book record or NULL if something goes wrong.         *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record* telephone_book_record_alloc(const char* last_name,
                                                   const char* first_name,
                                                   const char* phone_number,
                                                   int id);

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees the memory occupied by the telephone book record: all existing fields  *
* and the actual record.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_free(telephone_book_record* record);




/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes an empty telephone book record list.               *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new empty telephone book record list or NULL if something goes     *
* wrong.                                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

/*******************************************************************************
* Appends the argument telephone book record to the tail of the argument       *
* telephone book record list.                                                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a zero value if the operation was successfull. A non-zero value is   *
* returned if something fails.                                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_add_record(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                          telephone_book_record* record);

/*******************************************************************************
* Removes and returns the telephone book record that has 'id' as its record ID.*
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns NULL if something fails or the list does not contain record with ID  *
* 'id'. Otherwise, a removed record is returned.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record*
telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                        int id);

/*******************************************************************************
* Sorts the telephone records. The last name of each record is the primary     *
* sorting key, and the first name of each record is the secondary sorting key. *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if the sorting could not be    *
* completed.                                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_sort(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that each telephone book record has a unique ID.                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory occupied by the argument telephone book record list.    *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_list_free(telephone_book_record_list* list);

#endif /* TELEPHONE_BOOK_H */
```

> telephone_book.c

```
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include "telephone_book_utils.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the length of the telephone book record list.                        *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_size(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{

    return list ? list->size : -1;
}

static telephone_book_record_list_node*
telephone_book_record_list_node_alloc(telephone_book_record* record)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* node;

    if (!record)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    node = malloc(sizeof *node);

    if (!node)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    node->record = record;
    node->next = NULL;
    node->prev = NULL;

    return node;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes a new telephone book record.                       *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new telephone book record or NULL if something goes wrong.         *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record* telephone_book_record_alloc(const char* last_name,
                                                   const char* first_name,
                                                   const char* phone_number,
                                                   int id)
{
    telephone_book_record* record = malloc(sizeof *record);

    if (!record)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record->last_name        = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(last_name) + 1));
    record->first_name       = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(first_name) + 1));
    record->telephone_number = malloc(sizeof(char) *
                                      (strlen(phone_number) + 1));
    record->id = id;

    strcpy(record->last_name, last_name);
    strcpy(record->first_name, first_name);
    strcpy(record->telephone_number, phone_number);

    return record;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees the memory occupied by the telephone book record: all existing fields  *
* and the actual record.                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_free(telephone_book_record* record)
{
    if (!record)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (record->first_name)
    {
        free(record->first_name);
    }

    if (record->last_name)
    {
        free(record->last_name);
    }

    if (record->telephone_number)
    {
        free(record->telephone_number);
    }

    free(record);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and initializes an empty telephone book record list.               *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a new empty telephone book record list or NULL if something goes     *
* wrong.                                                                       *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_alloc()
{
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list = malloc(sizeof *record_list);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record_list->head = NULL;
    record_list->tail = NULL;
    record_list->size = 0;
    return record_list;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Appends the argument telephone book record to the tail of the argument       *
* telephone book record list.                                                  *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns a zero value if the operation was successfull. A non-zero value is   *
* returned if something fails.                                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_add_record(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                          telephone_book_record* record)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* new_node;

    if (!list || !record)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    new_node = telephone_book_record_list_node_alloc(record);

    if (!new_node)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (list->head)
    {
        new_node->prev = list->tail;
        list->tail->next = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = new_node;
    }

    list->tail = new_node;
    list->size++;
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Removes a telephone book record that has 'id' as its record ID.              *
* ---                                                                          *
* On error or ID mismatch returns NULL. Otherwise the record with the same ID  *
* (which is removed) is returned.                                              *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record*
telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                        int id)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* next_node;
    telephone_book_record* removed_record;

    if (!list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;

        /* Since the program makes sure that all IDs are unique, we can */
        /* return as soon as we remove the first match. */
        if (current_node->record->id == id)
        {
            if (current_node->prev)
            {
                current_node->prev->next = current_node->next;
            }
            else
            {
                list->head = current_node->next;
            }

            if (current_node->next)
            {
                current_node->next->prev = current_node->prev;
            }
            else
            {
                list->tail = current_node->prev;
            }

            removed_record = current_node->record;
            free(current_node);
            return removed_record;
        }

        current_node = next_node;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Defines a telephone book record comparator. The last name of a record is the *
* primary sorting key, and the first name is the secondary sorting key.        *
* ---
* Returns zero, if both the input records have the same last and first name.   *
* If the first entry should precede the second, a negative value is returned.  *
* If the second entry should precede the first, a positive value is returned.  *
*******************************************************************************/
static int record_cmp(const void* pa, const void* pb)
{
    int c;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* a =
    *(telephone_book_record_list_node *const *) pa;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* b =
    *(telephone_book_record_list_node *const *) pb;

    c = strcmp(a->record->last_name, b->record->last_name);

    if (c)
    {
        return c;
    }

    return strcmp(a->record->first_name, b->record->first_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Sorts the telephone records. The last name of each record is the primary     *
* sorting key, and the first name of each record is the secondary sorting key. *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if the sorting could not be    *
* completed.                                                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_sort(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node** array;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    int list_length;
    int index;

    if (!list)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    list_length = telephone_book_record_list_size(list);

    if (list_length == 0)
    {
        /* Nothing to sort. */
        return 0;
    }

    array = malloc(list_length * sizeof *array);

    if (!array)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    for (index = 0;
         index < list_length;
         index++, current_node = current_node->next)
    {
        array[index] = current_node;
    }

    qsort(array, list_length, sizeof *array, record_cmp);

    /* Relink the nodes: */
    list->head = array[0];
    list->tail = array[list_length - 1];

    list->head->prev = NULL;
    list->tail->next = NULL;

    for (index = 0; index < list_length - 1; ++index)
    {
        array[index]->next = array[index + 1];
    }

    for (index = 1; index < list_length; ++index)
    {
        array[index]->prev = array[index - 1];
    }

    /* Freeing memory! */
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Makes sure that each telephone book record has an unique ID.                 *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    int id;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    if (!list)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    id = 0;
    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_node->record->id = ++id;
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory occupied by the argument telephone book record list.    *
*******************************************************************************/
void telephone_book_record_list_free(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* next_node;

    if (!list)
    {
        return;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        next_node = current_node->next;
        telephone_book_record_free(current_node->record);
        free(current_node);
        current_node = next_node;
    }

    free(list);
}
```

> telephone_book_utils.h

```
#ifndef TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H
#define TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include "telephone_book.h"

#ifdef _WIN32
#define PATH_SEPARATOR '\\'
#else
#define PATH_SEPARATOR '/'
#endif

/*******************************************************************************
* This structures holds the string required for neat result output.            *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct {
    char* title_string;
    char* separator_string;
    char* record_format_string;
} output_table_strings;




/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a C string representing the full path to the telephone book record   *
* file.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns all format strings for printing the record list.         *
*******************************************************************************/
output_table_strings*
output_table_strings_create(telephone_book_record_list* list);

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns a structure containing all format strings necessary for  *
* printing the telephone book record list.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
void output_table_strings_free(output_table_strings* output_table_strs);

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the format string for nifty printing the removed records.            *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_removed_record_output_format_string(telephone_book_record_list* list);

#endif /* TELEPHONE_BOOK_UTILS_H */
```

> telephone_book_utils.c

```
#include "telephone_book_utils.h"
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

const char* TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME = ".telephone_book";

static const char* TITLE_LAST_NAME          = "Last name";
static const char* TITLE_FIRST_NAME         = "First name";
static const char* TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER   = "Telephone number";
static const char* TITLE_CONTACT_ID         = "ID";

static const size_t ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY = 40;
static const size_t FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY    = 100;

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns a C string representing the full path to the telephone book record   *
* file.                                                                        *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_telephone_record_book_file_path()
{
    char* home_directory;
    char* telephone_record_book_file_path;
    size_t home_directory_name_length;

    home_directory = getenv("HOME");

    if (!home_directory)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    home_directory_name_length = strlen(home_directory);

    /* Allocate the space for the entire */
    telephone_record_book_file_path =
    malloc(sizeof(char)
            * (home_directory_name_length
               + 2 + strlen(TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME)));

    if (!telephone_record_book_file_path)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(telephone_record_book_file_path, home_directory);

    telephone_record_book_file_path[home_directory_name_length] =
        PATH_SEPARATOR;

    strcpy(&telephone_record_book_file_path[home_directory_name_length + 1],
           TELEPHONE_RECORD_BOOK_FILE_NAME);

    return telephone_record_book_file_path;
}

static char* write_separator(char* str, char c, size_t n)
{
    memset(str, c, n);
    return str + n;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Allocates and sets a row separator string.                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
char* load_separator_string(size_t max_last_name_token_length,
                            size_t max_first_name_token_length,
                            size_t max_telephone_number_token_length,
                            size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length)
{
    char* save_separator_string;

    /* The separator string is composed of 4 horizontal bars: one bar for the
     * last name, one for first name, one for phone number, and one for the ID
     * (in that order). The magic constants 1 and 2, are the additional padding
     * so that for each attribute (column) there is a space before and after the
     * column title. 'max_first_name_token_length + 2' means that the longest
     * first name (or column) title is no longer than 
     * 'max_first_name_token_length', and it will be preceded and followed by 
     * one space.
     *
     * The magic constant 4, counts 3 bars between the columns and a final 
     * '\0' terminator.
     */
    char* separator_string =
    malloc((max_last_name_token_length + 1) +
           (max_first_name_token_length + 2) +
           (max_telephone_number_token_length + 2) +
           (max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1) + 4);

    if (!separator_string)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    save_separator_string = separator_string;
    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string,
                                       '-',
                                       max_last_name_token_length + 1);

    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string, '+', 1);
    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string,
                                       '-',
                                       max_first_name_token_length + 2);

    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string, '+', 1);
    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string,
                                       '-',
                                       max_telephone_number_token_length + 2);

    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string, '+', 1);
    separator_string = write_separator(separator_string,
                                       '-',
                                       max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1);

    write_separator(separator_string, '\0', 1);
    return save_separator_string;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Creates and returns a structure containing all format strings necessary for  *
* printing the telephone book record list.                                     *
*******************************************************************************/
output_table_strings*
output_table_strings_create(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    size_t max_last_name_token_length        = strlen(TITLE_LAST_NAME);
    size_t max_first_name_token_length       = strlen(TITLE_FIRST_NAME);
    size_t max_telephone_number_token_length = strlen(TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER);
    size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length   = strlen(TITLE_CONTACT_ID);

    size_t last_name_token_length;
    size_t first_name_token_length;
    size_t telephone_number_token_length;
    size_t telephone_contact_id_length;

    output_table_strings* output_table;

    /* The format string used to output the actual telephone book records. */
    char* record_format_string;

    /* The title string. */
    char* title_string;

    /* The separating horizontal bar. */
    char* separator_string;
    char* id_holder_string;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    if (!list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table */
    output_table = malloc(sizeof *output_table);

    if (!output_table)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, id_holder_string */
    id_holder_string = malloc(ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!id_holder_string)
    {
        free(output_table);
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_record = current_node->record;

        last_name_token_length  = strlen(current_record->last_name);
        first_name_token_length = strlen(current_record->first_name);
        telephone_number_token_length =
        strlen(current_record->telephone_number);

        sprintf(id_holder_string, "%d", current_record->id);
        telephone_contact_id_length = strlen(id_holder_string);

        max_last_name_token_length = MAX(max_last_name_token_length,
                                         last_name_token_length);

        max_first_name_token_length = MAX(max_first_name_token_length,
                                          first_name_token_length);

        max_telephone_number_token_length =
            MAX(max_telephone_number_token_length,
                telephone_number_token_length);

        max_telephone_contact_id_length = MAX(max_telephone_contact_id_length,
                                              telephone_contact_id_length);

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table */
    free(id_holder_string);

    /* ALLOCATED: output_table, record_format_string */
    record_format_string = malloc(FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!record_format_string)
    {
        free(output_table);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* This is really ad hoc, yet we want to keep the listing code as simple 
       as possible, so we opt to do the format magic in this routine. */
    sprintf(record_format_string,
            "%%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zus | %%-%zuzu\n",
            max_last_name_token_length,
            max_first_name_token_length,
            max_telephone_number_token_length,
            max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    /* @ALLOC: output_table, record_format_string, title_string */
    title_string = malloc((max_last_name_token_length + 1) +
                          (max_first_name_token_length + 2) +
                          (max_telephone_number_token_length + 2) +
                          (max_telephone_contact_id_length + 1) + 4);

    if (!title_string)
    {
        free(output_table);
        free(record_format_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    sprintf(title_string,
            "%-*s | %-*s | %-*s | %-*s",
            (int) max_last_name_token_length,
            TITLE_LAST_NAME,
            (int) max_first_name_token_length,
            TITLE_FIRST_NAME,
            (int) max_telephone_number_token_length,
            TITLE_TELEPHONE_NUMBER,
            (int) max_telephone_contact_id_length,
            TITLE_CONTACT_ID);

    /* @ALLOC: output_table, record_format_string, title_string, 
               separator_string*/
    separator_string =
        load_separator_string(max_last_name_token_length,
                              max_first_name_token_length,
                              max_telephone_number_token_length,
                              max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    if (!separator_string)
    {
        free(output_table);
        free(record_format_string);
        free(title_string);
        return NULL;
    }

    output_table->title_string = title_string;
    output_table->separator_string = separator_string;
    output_table->record_format_string = record_format_string;

    return output_table;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Frees all the memory alloated by the output table format strings.            *
*******************************************************************************/
void output_table_strings_free(output_table_strings* output_table_strs)
{
    if (!output_table_strs)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (output_table_strs->record_format_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->record_format_string);
    }

    if (output_table_strs->separator_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->separator_string);
    }

    if (output_table_strs->title_string)
    {
        free(output_table_strs->title_string);
    }

    free(output_table_strs);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the format string for nifty printing the removed records.            *
*******************************************************************************/
char* get_removed_record_output_format_string(telephone_book_record_list* list)
{
    size_t max_last_name_token_length        = 0;
    size_t max_first_name_token_length       = 0;
    size_t max_telephone_number_token_length = 0;
    size_t max_telephone_contact_id_length   = 0;

    size_t last_name_token_length;
    size_t first_name_token_length;
    size_t telephone_number_token_length;
    size_t telephone_contact_id_length;

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string */
    char* format_string = malloc(sizeof(char) * FORMAT_STRING_CAPACITY);
    char* id_holder_string;

    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    if (!format_string)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string, id_holder_string */
    id_holder_string = malloc(ID_HOLDER_STRING_CAPACITY);

    if (!id_holder_string)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        current_record = current_node->record;

        last_name_token_length  = strlen(current_record->last_name);
        first_name_token_length = strlen(current_record->first_name);
        telephone_number_token_length =
                                  strlen(current_record->telephone_number);

        sprintf(id_holder_string, "%d", current_record->id);
        telephone_contact_id_length = strlen(id_holder_string);

        max_last_name_token_length = MAX(max_last_name_token_length,
                                         last_name_token_length);

        max_first_name_token_length = MAX(max_first_name_token_length,
                                          first_name_token_length);

        max_telephone_number_token_length =
        MAX(max_telephone_number_token_length,
            telephone_number_token_length);

        max_telephone_contact_id_length = MAX(max_telephone_contact_id_length,
                                              telephone_contact_id_length);
        current_node = current_node->next;
    }



    sprintf(format_string,
            "%%-%zus %%-%zus %%-%zus %%-%zuzu\n",
            max_last_name_token_length,
            max_first_name_token_length,
            max_telephone_number_token_length,
            max_telephone_contact_id_length);

    /* ALLOCATED: format_string */
    free(id_holder_string);
    return format_string;
}
```

> telephone_book_io.h

```
#ifndef telephone_book_io_h
#define telephone_book_io_h

#include "telephone_book.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/*******************************************************************************
* Reconstructs the telephone book record list from a file pointed to by the    *
* argument file handle.                                                        *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns the record list on success, and NULL on failure.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(FILE* f);

/*******************************************************************************
* Writes the entire contents of the telephone record list to a specified file  *
* handle.                                                                      *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                             FILE* f);


#endif /* telephone_book_io_h */
```

> telephone_book_io.c

```
#include "telephone_book_io.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "64"
#define MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH 65

/*******************************************************************************
* Reconstructs the telephone book record list from a file pointed to by the    *
* argument file handle.                                                        *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns the record list on success, and NULL on failure.                     *
*******************************************************************************/
telephone_book_record_list* telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(FILE* f)
{
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record* current_record;

    char last_name_token   [MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    char first_name_token  [MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    char phone_number_token[MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH];
    int  id_holder;
    int read_result;

    if (!f)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    if (!record_list)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f))
    {
        read_result = fscanf(f,
                             "%" MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %"  MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %"  MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
                             %d\n",
                             last_name_token,
                             first_name_token,
                             phone_number_token,
                             &id_holder);

        if (read_result == 4)
        {
            current_record = telephone_book_record_alloc(last_name_token,
                                                         first_name_token,
                                                         phone_number_token,
                                                         id_holder);
            if (!current_record)
            {
                telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
                return NULL;
            }

            telephone_book_record_list_add_record(record_list, current_record);
        }
    }

    return record_list;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Writes the entire contents of the telephone record list to a specified file  *
* handle.                                                                      *
* ---                                                                          *
* Returns zero on success, and a non-zero value if something fails.            *
*******************************************************************************/
int telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(telephone_book_record_list* list,
                                             FILE* f)
{
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;

    if (!list || !f)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    if (list->size == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    current_node = list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        fprintf(f,
                "%s %s %s %d\n",
                current_node->record->last_name,
                current_node->record->first_name,
                current_node->record->telephone_number,
                current_node->record->id);

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> main.c

```
#include "telephone_book.h"
#include "telephone_book_io.h"
#include "telephone_book_utils.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char* OPTION_ADD_SHORT = "-a";
static const char* OPTION_ADD_LONG  = "--add";

static const char* OPTION_REMOVE_SHORT = "-r";
static const char* OPTION_REMOVE_LONG  = "--remove";

static const char* OPTION_HELP_SHORT = "-h";
static const char* OPTION_HELP_LONG  = "--help";

static const size_t RECORDS_PER_BLOCK = 3;

/*******************************************************************************
* Returns the smallest of 'a', 'b', and 'c'.                                   *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t min3(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c)
{
    if (a < b)
    {
        if (c < a)
        {
            return c;
        }

        return a;
    }

    /* b <= a */
    if (c < b)
    {
        return c;
    }

    return b;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Prints the help message to the standard output.                              *
*******************************************************************************/
static void print_help(char* executable_name)
{
    char path_separator = PATH_SEPARATOR;
    int executable_name_length = (int) strlen(executable_name);
    int i;

    /* Doing my own basename for the sake of portability. */
    for (i = executable_name_length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        if (executable_name[i] == path_separator)
        {
            executable_name = &executable_name[i + 1];
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("Usage: %s -a    LAST FIRST NUMBER\n", executable_name);
    printf("       %s --add LAST FIRST NUMBER\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    printf("       %s -r       ID1 ID2 ... IDn\n", executable_name);
    printf("       %s --remove ID1 ID2 ... IDn\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    printf("(1)    %s\n",                      executable_name);
    printf("(2)    %s LAST_EXPR\n",            executable_name);
    printf("(3)    %s - FIRST_EXPR\n",         executable_name);
    printf("(4)    %s LAST_EXPR FIRST_EXPR\n", executable_name);
    puts("");
    puts("Where: -a or --add for adding one new book entry.");
    puts("       -r or --remove for removing book entries by their IDs.");
    puts("");
    puts("(1) List all book entries in order.");
    puts("(2) Match by last name and list the closest book entries.");
    puts("(3) Match by first name and list the closest book entries.");
    puts("(4) Match by both last and first names and list the closest book "
         "entries");
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements the Levenshtein distance algorithm.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t edit_distance(char* word1,
                            char* word2,
                            size_t length1,
                            size_t length2)
{
    int cost;

    if (length1 == 0)
    {
        return length2;
    }

    if (length2 == 0)
    {
        return length1;
    }

    cost = tolower(word1[length1 - 1]) ==
           tolower(word2[length2 - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

    return min3(edit_distance(word1, word2, length1, length2 - 1) + 1,
                edit_distance(word1, word2, length1 - 1, length2) + 1,
                edit_distance(word1, word2, length1 - 1, length2 - 1) + cost);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Computes the Levenshtein disance between words 'word1' and 'word2'.          *
*******************************************************************************/
static size_t compute_edit_distance(char* word1, char* word2)
{
    return edit_distance(word1, word2, strlen(word1), strlen(word2));
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Implements listing the telephone book records.                               *
*******************************************************************************/
int command_list_telephone_book_records_impl(
                        telephone_book_record_list* record_list,
                        char* last_name,
                        char* first_name)
{
    size_t best_tentative_distance = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    size_t temp_distance;
    size_t i;
    output_table_strings* output_strings;
    telephone_book_record* record;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    telephone_book_record_list* best_record_list =
        telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    /* ALLOCATED: best_record_list */
    if (!best_record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate the best record list.", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    current_node = record_list->head;

    while (current_node)
    {
        temp_distance =
        (last_name ?
            compute_edit_distance(last_name,
                                  current_node->record->last_name) : 0) +
        (first_name ?
            compute_edit_distance(first_name,
                                  current_node->record->first_name) : 0);

        if (best_tentative_distance > temp_distance)
        {
            /* 'temp_distance' improves the best known edit distance,     */
            /* clear the current best list and append the current record: */
            telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
            best_record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

            if (!best_record_list)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate new best record list.", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            record = telephone_book_record_alloc(
                            current_node->record->last_name,
                            current_node->record->first_name,
                            current_node->record->telephone_number,
                            current_node->record->id);

            if (!record)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate a copy record.", stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(best_record_list, record))
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot add a new record to the best list.",
                      stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                telephone_book_record_free(record);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }

            best_tentative_distance = temp_distance;
        }
        else if (best_tentative_distance == temp_distance)
        {
            /* Append the current record to the best list: */
            record = telephone_book_record_alloc(
                            current_node->record->last_name,
                            current_node->record->first_name,
                            current_node->record->telephone_number,
                            current_node->record->id);

            if (!record)
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate a copy record.", stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }


            if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(best_record_list, record))
            {
                fputs("ERROR: Cannot add a new record to the best list.",
                      stderr);
                telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
                telephone_book_record_free(record);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    output_strings = output_table_strings_create(best_record_list);

    if (!output_strings)
    {
        telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts(output_strings->separator_string);
    puts(output_strings->title_string);
    puts(output_strings->separator_string);

    current_node = best_record_list->head;
    i = 0;

    while (current_node)
    {
        printf(output_strings->record_format_string,
               current_node->record->last_name,
               current_node->record->first_name,
               current_node->record->telephone_number,
               current_node->record->id);

        current_node = current_node->next;
        ++i;

        if (current_node && i % RECORDS_PER_BLOCK == 0)
        {
            puts(output_strings->separator_string);
        }
    }

    output_table_strings_free(output_strings);
    telephone_book_record_list_free(best_record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the command for listing the records.                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_list_telephone_book_records(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    char* last_name;
    char* first_name;

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(get_telephone_record_book_file_path(), "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* If fails, silently ignore: */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    /* Does not ask for resources, should be OK: */
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    /* "w" means overwrite the file. */
    f = fopen(file_name, "w");

    if (f)
    {
        /* Write the file back. It will update the order of the records and */
        /* fix the record IDs, if needed. */
        telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f);
        fclose(f);
    }

    last_name  = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : NULL;
    first_name = argc >= 3 ? argv[2] : NULL;

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-") == 0)
    {
        /* Match all last names: */
        last_name = NULL;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: record_list */
    free(file_name);

    return command_list_telephone_book_records_impl(record_list,
                                                    last_name,
                                                    first_name);
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the command for adding a new record.                                 *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_add_record(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record* record;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list, record */
    record = telephone_book_record_alloc(argv[2], argv[3], argv[4], -1);

    if (!record)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the new record.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_add_record(record_list, record))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot add the new entry to the record book.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_free(record);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Even if the following two functions fail, proceed further. */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    f = fopen(file_name, "w");
    free(file_name);

    if (!f)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot open the record book file.", stderr);
        /* 'record' is contained in 'record_list' so is freed by it: */
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_free(record);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot update the record book file.", stderr);
    }

    fclose(f);
    /* 'record' is contained in 'record_list' so is freed by it: */
    telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Handles the commmand for removing records by their IDs.                      *
*******************************************************************************/
static int command_remove_records(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char* file_name;
    FILE* f;
    telephone_book_record_list* record_list;
    telephone_book_record_list* removed_record_list;
    telephone_book_record* removed_record;
    telephone_book_record_list_node* current_node;
    char* removed_record_format;
    int arg_index;
    int id;

    if (argc < 3)
    {
        puts("Warning: no record IDs given. Nothing to remove.");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name */
    file_name = get_telephone_record_book_file_path();

    if (!file_name)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the telephone book file name.",
              stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    f = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!f)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,
                "ERROR: Cannot open the record book file '%s'.\n",
                file_name);

        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list */
    record_list = telephone_book_record_list_read_from_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    if (!record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot read the record book file.", stderr);
        free(file_name);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* ALLOCATED: file_name, record_list, removed_record_list */
    removed_record_list = telephone_book_record_list_alloc();

    if (!removed_record_list)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory for the list of removed records.",
              stderr);
        free(file_name);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Even if the following two functions fail, proceed further. */
    telephone_book_record_list_sort(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_fix_ids(record_list);

    f = fopen(file_name, "w");

    /* ALLOCATED: record_list, removed_record_list */
    free(file_name); /* We do not need 'file_name' anymore. */

    if (!f)
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot open the record book file for writing.", stderr);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (arg_index = 2; arg_index < argc; ++arg_index)
    {
        sscanf(argv[arg_index], "%d", &id);
        removed_record = telephone_book_record_list_remove_entry(record_list,
                                                                 id);

        if (removed_record)
        {
            telephone_book_record_list_add_record(removed_record_list,
                                                  removed_record);
        }
    }

    if (telephone_book_record_list_write_to_file(record_list, f))
    {
        fputs("ERROR: Cannot update the record book file.", stderr);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
        telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
        fclose(f);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(f);

    printf("Number of records to remove: %d, removed: %d.\n",
           argc - 2,
           telephone_book_record_list_size(removed_record_list));
    puts("List of removed entries:");
    current_node = removed_record_list->head;
    removed_record_format =
        get_removed_record_output_format_string(removed_record_list);

    while (current_node)
    {
        if (removed_record_format)
        {
            printf(removed_record_format,
                   current_node->record->last_name,
                   current_node->record->first_name,
                   current_node->record->telephone_number,
                   current_node->record->id);
        }
        else
        {
            /* Fallback format output: */
            printf("%s, %s - %s, ID %d\n",
                   current_node->record->last_name,
                   current_node->record->first_name,
                   current_node->record->telephone_number,
                   current_node->record->id);
        }

        current_node = current_node->next;
    }

    if (removed_record_format)
    {
        free(removed_record_format);
    }

    telephone_book_record_list_free(record_list);
    telephone_book_record_list_free(removed_record_list);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        return command_list_telephone_book_records(argc, argv);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_HELP_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_HELP_LONG) == 0)
    {
        print_help(argv[0]);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_ADD_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_ADD_LONG) == 0)
    {
        return command_add_record(argc, argv);
    }

    if (strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_REMOVE_SHORT) == 0 ||
        strcmp(argv[1], OPTION_REMOVE_LONG) == 0)
    {
        return command_remove_records(argc, argv);
    }

    return command_list_telephone_book_records(argc, argv);
}
```

As always, any critique is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Architecture**

With the function set posted, there is no *need* for the `struct telephone_book_record_list_node* prev` field.   Iterating through a linked link can keep track of the previous node if needed rather than obliging millions of records to maintain a `prev` field.

**Functionality**

If the record scanned does not return 4, exit the loop or handle the error  - do not ignore it.  Code has no handling of reading only  1 to 3 fields and instead code could create subsequent bogus records.

```
//while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f)) {
//    read_result = fscanf(f,
//    ...
//    if (read_result == 4)
while (fscanf(f, ... ) == 4) {
```

`puts()` always appends a `'\n'` to the output.  This prevents `separator_string` and others from printing without a line-feed if desired.  Suggest allowing such formatting to occur without an obligatory `'\n'` should the user opt for that.

```
// puts(output_strings->separator_string); // \n appended
fputs(output_strings->separator_string, stdout);  // \n not appended
```

Consider allowing other sorting funcitons.  [Example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/sorting-collations.html)

**Defensive Coding**

Test for valid telephone number characters.  E. g. `"0123456789*#-,."`

**Minor**

1) Do not repeat.  The same comment exist in 2 files.  This obliges a maintainer to update comments twice, all too often resulting in their content diverging.  Suggest referencing comments.

```
/************...
* See telephone_book.h
*************...*/
void telephone_book_record_free(telephone_book_record* record) {
  ...
}
```

2) `if(NULL-ness test)` not need. `free(NULL);` is OK.  (Used in multiple places.)

```
// if (record->first_name) {
//    free(record->first_name);
// }
free(record->first_name);
```

3) Check the result of `*scanf()` and friends.  But this is in the test driver, so a minor point.

```
// sscanf(argv[arg_index], "%d", &id);
if (sscanf(argv[arg_index], "%d", &id) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

4) Not a fan of style `MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING` code

```
//#define MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "64"
//    read_result = fscanf(f,
//                         "%" MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\
//                         %"  MAX_RECORD_TOKEN_LENGTH_STRING "s\

// Alternative
#define TOKEN_SCAN_FMT "%64s"

read_result = fscanf(f, TOKEN_SCAN_FMT TOKEN_SCAN_FMT TOKEN_SCAN_FMT "%d\n", 
    last_name_token, first_name_token, phone_number_token, &id_holder);
```

5) `* sizeof (char)` serves little purpose - it is *always* `(size_t)1`.  Drop it or if code should correlate to the type of `telephone_record_book_file_path` references, than use that directly.

```
// telephone_record_book_file_path = malloc(sizeof(char) * 
//    (home_directory_name_length ...));
telephone_record_book_file_path = malloc(home_directory_name_length ...);
// or
telephone_record_book_file_path = malloc(sizeof *telephone_record_book_file_path * 
    (home_directory_name_length ...));
```

**Comment**

Good use of `size_t` and allocation coding style.  Nicely laid out code although I find the indenting not amenable to auto formatting.

Comment: **`read_result = fscanf(f, TOKEN_SCAN_FMT, TOKEN_SCAN_FMT, TOKEN_SCAN_FMT "%d\n",`** Are you sure that there should be commas between **`TOKEN_SCAN_FMT`** s?

Comment: @coderodde Good eye.  Removed the 2 commas to allow string literal concatenation.